# yy_top_state() seems to fail with flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

So i'm writing this reentrant scanner with flex and i'm using the stack option to track state. According to the documentation, it seems that

```
yy_push_state(SCRIPT, yyscanner);
//now yy_top_state(yyscanner)  == SCRIPT; should eval true right?
```

but when i put the following printf() immediately after yy_push_state()

```
printf("SCRIPT=%d; DQUOTE=%d; CURRENT=%d\n", SCRIPT, DQUOTE, 
       yy_top_state(yyscanner));
```

I get this in return for output

```
SCRIPT=2; DQUOTE=3; CURRENT=1
```

Please point out what i'm doing wrong if anything at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what value where you expecting; that is what is the value of NEWSTATE?

Comment: sloppy question, my bad. NEWSTATE was psuedo for SCRIPT. which is to say i'm really executing yy_push_state(SCRIPT, yyscanner); but yy_top_state() doesn't seem to track this.*fixed*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Based on the code I've seen, it's the *current* state that gets pushed on the stack, then the state is then changed to the new state.

After expanding the stack if necessary, [`yy_push_state(new_state)`](http://tbingmann.com/2007/flex-bison-cpp-example/flex-bison-cpp-example-0.1.2/doxygen-html/scanner_8cc-source.html#l01738) executes:

```
(yy_start_stack)[(yy_start_stack_ptr)++] = YY_START;
BEGIN(new_state);
```

where `YY_START` is a macro based on the current state and `BEGIN` is what sets the new state.